# opts_chunk$set no longer works

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have the latest versions of R, RStudio, and knitr installed. My RMarkdown file compiles fine when I compile i RStudio with the Knit HTML icon, but is I add this line near the top of my file:

```
`r opts_chunk$set(tidy=FALSE,fig.width=6,fig.height=5)`
```

It no longer compiles. I get this error:

```
processing file: ApproxBinomWithNorm.Rmd
Quitting from lines 2-29 (ApproxBinomWithNorm.Rmd) 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'opts_chunk' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... in_dir -> inline_exec -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

What has changed. I've used this opts_chunk command for over a year.

Comment: Could you try `knitr::opts_chunk` instead of `opts_chunk`?

Comment: The command `r knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy=FALSE,fig.width=6,fig.height=5)`worked.

Comment: @Yihui Wouldn’t you agree that this is a bug though? I.e. `knitr::knit` should ensure that the `knitr` package is properly loaded *and attached*?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Attaching a package without user's permission is intrusive since it exposes all exported objects in the package in the work space, and users may not want all of them. I understand this is a little bit annoying, but I guess `library(knitr)` is not super hard to type... I'll add a note to the documentation of the rmarkdown package to emphasize this change.

Comment: @Yihui Of course – ideally – the import should happen in an isolated environment so that it has no side-effect outside the `knit` call. This isn’t particularly hard to realise (`if (not_detached) { library((knitr); on.exit(detach('package:knitr'))}`). Certainly the user expects the library to be loaded inside the template. You could even make this a documented behaviour, if actually necessary.

Comment: @Yihui et al, not sure if you understand what I am reporting. I have a host of files written over the past two semesters at http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math15/RActivities.php. RMarkdown, combined with KnitHTML in RStudio has been absolutely fabulous. However, if you check some of my source files on this page, you'll see that I put the following line near the top of most of the source files: `r opts_chunk$set(tidy=FALSE,fig.width=6,fig.height=5)`. The source files used to compile just fine, but with the current updates, they no longer compile.

Comment: What they do is give the following error: processing file: anova.Rmd
Quitting from lines 2-18 (anova.Rmd) 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'opts_chunk' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... in_dir -> inline_exec -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted. If I change the command to `r knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy=FALSE,fig.width=6,fig.height=5)`, then the file compiles. That is the bug I am reporting.

Comment: Also, it appears you edited my question, inferring that I was using an R script, which I am not using.